# Is there a way I can get a row/seq number in the output of a select with SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have this SQL:

```
SELECT English, F1, F3, F3, F4, F5, Hidden, PhraseId FROM Phrase
```

What I would like to do is to return in addition to this a number for each record selected.

So for example the query would return:

```
1  f1result f2result f3result etc
2  f1result f2result f3result etc
```

Comment: If you're not using a sqlite version that supports window functions, it's easier to implement the row number in the program that's executing the query - increment a counter each time you fetch a row. Whatever you do, don't make the common mistake of confusing rowid with row number.

Answer (score 3):

In the more recent versions of SQLite, you can use [`row_number()`](https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html):

```
SELECT row_number() over (order by English) as seqnum
       English, F1, F3, F3, F4, F5, Hidden, PhraseId
FROM Phrase;
```

In older versions, this is much harder, requiring a correlated subquery -- and it will not work well on larger amounts of data.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `row_number()` like below if your version support

```
SELECT 
 row_number() overr(order by (select null)) rn
,English, F1, F3, F3, F4, F5, Hidden, PhraseId FROM Phrase
```